# How to save a csv file in JFileChooser ?

Tags: java, swing, csv

Hi I am not able to save a csv file.I am not even getting error in the write command.I have used FileChooser. And can any one explain the use of Approve option as i am new to swing.

```
if(e.getActionCommand()=="SaveTweet")
         {
        JFileChooser savePlaylistDialog = new JFileChooser();
        savePlaylistDialog.setSelectedFile(new File( ".csv"));
        int status = savePlaylistDialog.showSaveDialog(savePlaylistDialog);

        try {   
            if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {    
                File savePlaylist = savePlaylistDialog.getSelectedFile();                                            

        ICsvListWriter csvWriter = null;
         try { 
              TwitterProject obj=new TwitterProject();
             String [][] tweet=obj.generateBottweet(username,interval,Btweet,no);  

               csvWriter = new CsvListWriter(new FileWriter("savePlaylist"), 

           CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

               for (int i = 0; i < tweet.length; i++) {
               csvWriter.write(tweet[i]);
             }

      } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace(); 
      } finally {
         try {
         System.out.println("closing file");
         csvWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
             }
      }

      } else if (status == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                // User has pressed cancel button
  }
 } catch (Exception ex) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File could not be written, try again.");
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things jump out...

First, you comparing Object reference of `String` instead of contents...

```
if(e.getActionCommand()=="SaveTweet")
```

Will very rarely be true, as the Object references will most likely never be equal, instead, you should try using something like...

```
if("SaveTweet".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
```

Which will compare the contents of the two `String`s, but will also guard against possible `NullPointerException`s...

Second, you are ignoring the `File` the the user selected, for example, you get a reference to the file the user selects using...

```
File savePlaylist = savePlaylistDialog.getSelectedFile();
```

But then you create a `FileWriter` which simply uses a `String` value...

```
csvWriter = new CsvListWriter(new FileWriter("savePlaylist"));
```

Instead, should try using something like...

```
csvWriter = new CsvListWriter(new FileWriter(savePlaylist));
```

Which will write the contents to the file that the user selects...

ps- I would also drop...

```
savePlaylistDialog.setSelectedFile(new File( ".csv"));
```

As it doesn't actually make sense, I doubt there would be file called `.csv`...or more to the point, it's highly unlikely...

Comment: The problem was in this statement                            csvWriter = new CsvListWriter(new FileWriter("savePlaylist"));     I removed the quotes and it worked fine .... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To compare String objects in java use .equals() method instead of "==" operator

change

```
if(e.getActionCommand()=="SaveTweet")
```

to

```
if("SaveTweet".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
```

if you want to ignore the case use like below code

```
if("SaveTweet".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you also test the writing method? Which implementation of csvwriter do you use? In some cases (com.csvwriter) you need to call flush() before close().